# c++ base class contain instance of a derived class

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how I might be able to implement something similar to this:

```
namespace advanced_cpp_oop
{
  class A
  {
    B b;
  };

  class B : public A
  {
  };
}

int main()
{
}
```

Where an instance of a base class can contain an instance of a derived class? When the above code is compiled the following error is generated:

```
g++ advanced_cpp_oop.cpp 
advanced_cpp_oop.cpp:8:5: error: ‘B’ does not name a type
```

The (almost) equivalent Java code which does compile is:

```
public class AdvancedCppOop
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a;
  }
}

class A
{
  B b;
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Really, if you think about it, that's kind of silly. An `A` would have a certain size (including the embedded `B`), say `N` bytes. But then a `B` would be at least as big, since it contains all the fields an `A` does, so `A` needs to be bigger to accomodate, which means `B` needs to be bigger, .....  Also, the `B` that an `A` contains must contain an `A` as it's base object, and that `A` must contain a `B`, which must contain an `A`, ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a pointer and a forward declaration:

```
namespace advanced_cpp_oop
{
  class B;

  class A
  {
    B* b;
  };

  class B : public A
  {
  };
}
```

In your C++ code, you are creating an instance of your `class B` inside `class A`, which is not possible since the compiler does not yet know anything (especially not the size) of `class B`.

With the code from my answer, you need to dynamically allocate an instance of `class B` and assign it to the `b` pointer somewhere else in your code.

On a side note, from design perspective, this does not really make sense since a parent class should not depend on a sub class.

Comment: Yep, exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do it with some type of pointer, such as unique_ptr, and a forward declaration:

```
  class B;

  class A
  {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
  };

  class B : public A
  {
  };
```

This is silly though and you should probably rethink your design.

Comment: Coplein's "Envelope/Letter" and related idioms come to mind--sometimes it makes sense to do so...

Answer (score 3):

There is one very important difference between C++ and Java. C++ is a language with value semantics, while Java is a language with reference semantics. When in Java you create a variable of anything other than a primitive type, you are not creating an object of that type, but a reference to such an object. On the contrary, in C++ the same construct refers to an actual object.

If you keep this in mind, it is simple to understand why the following cannot possibly work:

```
class Base {
   Derived d;
};
class Derived : Base {};
```

The first definition in C++ means that the object Base contains internally (not by reference) an object of type Derived. At the same time, Derived contains by means of inheritance a subobject of type Base.

That means that Derived contains a Base that contains a Derived containing a Base... 
What would be the size of Base or Derived?

In a language with reference semantics, or in C++ if you use pointers, that is not a problem. The Base object contains a *reference/pointer* to Derived. Derived contains a Base subobject by means of inheritance. The size of Base is well known: all the other fields plus the size of a reference/pointer. The size of Derived is whatever the size of Base is plus any extra members that are added.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas beat me to the correct answer, but I'll just add that the Java code works only because Java objects are implicitly held by pointers (hence the `B b = new B(...);` statements sprinkled throughout Java code) even if it doesn't look like it.  Your original C++ code doesn't work (even with a forward declaration of class B added) because the compiler doesn't know how big a B object is, and thus doesn't know how big an A object that contains it will be.  On the other hand, all pointers have the same size (regardless of pointed-to type), so the compiler has no such problems when you replace a B object with a pointer to a B object in class A.