# Derived class instance in the base class

Tags: c++, derived-class, member-variables

This is the code I'm trying to understand. It has no specific use. I'm just trying to understand what happens.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class derivedClass;
class baseClass
{
public:
    int objID;
    derivedClass* dcObjPtr;

    baseClass()
    {
        cout << "(1) Default constructor" << objID << endl;
    }

    baseClass(int ID)
    {
        objID = ID;
        dcObjPtr = new derivedClass(1);
        cout << "(2) Constructing base object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    derivedClass()
    {}

    derivedClass(int ID) : baseClass(ID)
    {
        cout << "(4) Constructing derived object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    derivedClass dcObj(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Using VS2013 I get the error "derivedClass: class has no constructors", which I don't think is the right error.

I was first using a derivedClass instance, not a pointer. And that was giving me a weird error about a semicolon. Then I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286534/c-base-class-contain-instance-of-a-derived-class) where the accepted answer was to have a pointer, instead of an instance.

These are the questions I have:

1. Why is the compiler complaining about no constructors. The class clearly has constructors.
2. How would this work? When we create an instance of dervedClass, there is a baseClass part in it. And this baseClass part has a derivedClass in it, and so on. This is recursive. I would assume if it works it would result in a segmentation fault or something like that. Am I right to assume that this would be recursive (if it works)?

Cheers.

Comment: In order to say `dcObjPtr = new derivedClass(1);` you need the class definition, which you don't have at that point. If you "fix" that you'll get an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making use of the definition of `derivedClass` before it's defined, by calling `new derivedClass` in the `baseClass` constructor. What you need to do is move the constructor definition outside `baseClass` and after `derivedClass`, like so:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class derivedClass;
class baseClass
{
public:
    int objID;
    derivedClass* dcObjPtr;

    baseClass()
    {
        cout << "(1) Default constructor" << objID << endl;
    }

    baseClass(int ID);

};

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
public:
    derivedClass()
    {}

    derivedClass(int ID) : baseClass(ID)
    {
        cout << "(4) Constructing derived object with ID: " << objID << endl;
    }
};

baseClass::baseClass(int ID)
{
    objID = ID;
    dcObjPtr = new derivedClass(1);
    cout << "(2) Constructing base object with ID: " << objID << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    derivedClass dcObj(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I note that running this [on ideone](http://ideone.com/hOzQKD) compiles, but hits a runtime error. I haven't investigated what that is.

Comment: Ah, of course. It's the infinite recursion juanchopanza mentions.

Comment: @Chowlett Thank you. But why can't the compiler say so? If the definition is missing, shouldn't there be a linker error?

Comment: @madu It _does_ say so. Sort of. At the line the error is on - the line in baseClass::baseClass that calls `new derivedClass` - the only information the compiler has about `derivedClass` is the forward declaration. So, as far as the compiler knows _at that point_, `derivedClass` has no constructors.